# group by one column, find min and max values based on that column and calculate average doing sliding window awk

Tags: awk

I am doing a sliding window analysis over some genomic data and I used awk to do it.

- Column 1: represent the Chromosome name.
- Column 2 and 3: represent positions (0-based notation).
- Column 4 and 5: values of interest.

What I need to do it to take X rows (being X the window size) and:

1. Get all distinct values of column 1 (i.e. all different chromosome within this window)
2. Get min value of column 2 for every different value in column 1 (i.e. for each chromosome, the min value)
3. Get max value of column 3 for every different value in column 1 (i.e. for each chromosome, the max value)
4. Average value of column 4.
5. Average value of column 5.

Then start the same process (taking X rows) but starting Y rows below (i.e. window step=Y).

For example, let's imagine that I use a window size of 10 (X=10) and window step of 5 (Y=5). An example of my data could be:

```
A   85  86  .043    .021                
A   86  87  .031    .014                
A   87  88  .035    .016                
A   88  89  .033    .015                
A   89  90  .031    .014                
A   90  91  .031    .014                
A   91  92  .032    .015                
B   1   2   .030    .013                
B   2   3   .038    .018                
B   3   4   .032    .014                
B   4   5   .030    .013                
B   5   6   .034    .016                
B   6   7   .032    .015                
B   10  11  .033    .015                
B   11  12  .045    .022                
B   12  13  .055    .029                
B   13  14  .059    .032                
B   20  21  .058    .031                
B   22  23  .059    .031                
B   24  25  .064    .035                
B   26  27  .063    .034                
B   28  29  .058    .031                
B   30  31  .063    .034                
B   108 109 .063    .034                
B   109 110 .067    .037                
B   110 111 .066    .037                
B   111 112 .061    .033                
B   112 113 .061    .033                
B   113 114 .056    .029                
B   114 115 .058    .031
```

And my desired output would be:

```
10  A_85_92;B_1_4   0.0336  0.0154
15  A_90_91;B_1_12  0.0337  0.0155
20  B_4_25  0.0469  0.0239
25  B_12_110    0.0609  0.0328
30  B_26_115    0.0616  0.0333
```

This output has:

- First column: Window identifier. Could be first or last NR of the window. In this case is the last NR, which is 10, 15, etc.-
- Different chromosome within that window, and start (min) and end (max) position within each chromosome. In this example for the first window (from row 1 to row 10) I have A and B chromosomes, A that goes from position 85 to position 92, and B going from position 1 to 4. Positions are separated using "_" and chromosomes using ";", but that is not mandatory.
- The average values calculated over column $4 and $5. In our example 0.0336 and 0.0154 respectively.

The next window goes then from row 5 to row 15, and then 10 to 20 and then 15 to 25, and so on.

So far I get here:

```
    awk -v OFS="\t" 'BEGIN{window=10;step=5}  
{
mod=NR%window; if(NR<=window){count++}
else
{ N[$1]++;{min=$2}{if ($2 < min) min = $2};{max=$3}{if ($3 > max) max = $3}; sum1-=array1[mod]; sum2-=array2[mod]}
sum1+=$4;
sum2+=$5;
array1[mod]=$4;
array2[mod]=$5;
} 
(NR%slide)==0{for (p in N) print NR,p, max, min, sum1/count, sum2/count}'  toy
```

Which results in:

```
15  B   11  12  0.0337  0.0155
20  B   24  25  0.0469  0.0239
25  B   109 110 0.0609  0.0328
30  B   114 115 0.0616  0.0333
```

So, I am not being able to properly get all the chromosome within the window and the min and max value for each of the chromosome. Also I am skyping the first windows that should be 10 and I don't know why.

Any input? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN {
    winSize = 10
    winStep = 5
    OFS = "\t"
}
{ buf[NR % winSize] = $0 }
(NR >= winSize) && ((NR % winStep) == 0) { prt() }

function prt(   sum,f,i,idx,beg,end,prev,ranges) {
    for (i=1; i<=winSize; i++) {
        idx = (NR+i) % winSize
        split(buf[idx],f)

        if ( f[1] != prev ) {
            ranges = (i > 1 ? ranges end ";" : "") f[1] "_" f[2] "_"
            prev = f[1]
        }
        end = f[3]

        sum[4] += f[4]
        sum[5] += f[5]
    }

    print NR, ranges end, sum[4] / winSize, sum[5] / winSize
}
```

.

```
$ awk -f tst.awk file
10  A_85_92;B_1_4   0.0336  0.0154
15  A_90_92;B_1_12  0.0337  0.0155
20  B_4_25  0.0469  0.0239
25  B_12_110    0.0609  0.0328
30  B_26_115    0.0616  0.0333
```

Comment: This is almost there. Thanks a lot. Only that I need to have min and max value for every distinct values in the first column. I edited the question and hopefully is clearer now.

Comment: OK I updated my answer. I think you have a mistake in your expected output such that `A_90_91` should be `A_90_92`.

Answer (score 0):

Despite the fact that Ed Morton already gave an accepted solution, i wanted to share my solution.

Difference is that the min/max/average is calculated for the value in the first column, and not for the group of the last x-lines.

output:

```
5 A_85_90   0.0346 0.016
10 A_90_92   0.0126 0.0058
10 A_85_92   0.00063 0.00109
10 B_1_4   0.02 0.009
15 B_4_12   0.0348 0.0162
20 B_12_25   0.059 0.0316
20 B_4_25   0.00295 0.00239
25 B_26_110   0.0628 0.034
30 B_110_115   0.0604 0.0326
30 B_26_115   0.00302 0.00333
```

script:

```
function init(x) {
        pmin[x]=min[x];
        pmax[x]=max[x];
        ps4[x]=s4[s];
        ps5[x]=s5[x];
        min[x]=maxvalue;
        max[x]=-maxvalue;
        s4[x]=0;
        s5[x]=0
}
function calcWindow(x) {
        if ((pmin[x]!=maxvalue) && pmin[x]!="") {
                cmin=pmin[x]<min[x] ? pmin[x] : min[x];
                cmax=pmax[x]>max[x] ? pmax[x] : max[x];
                cs4=(ps4[x]+s4[x])/window;
                cs5=(ps5[x]+s5[x])/window;
                print NR, x "_" cmin "_" cmax, " ", cs4/window, cs5/window ;
        }
}
BEGIN {
        maxvalue=999999;
        window=10;
        windowstep=5;
}
{
        if (!($1 in min)) { init($1) }
        if ($2<min[$1]) { min[$1]=$2 }
        if ($3>max[$1]) { max[$1]=$3 }
        s4[$1]+=$4;
        s5[$1]+=$5;
}
NR%windowstep==0{
        for (i in min) {
                if (min[i]!=maxvalue) {
                        print NR, i "_" min[i] "_" max[i], " ", s4[i]/windowstep, s5[i]/windowstep ;
                        if (NR%window==0) calcWindow(i);
                        init(i);
                }
        }
}
```

Comment: When doing min/max calculations always just init the min/max variable to the first value read from the input, not to some arbitrary number like `999999` that you **hope** will be larger/smaller than the values in the input, i.e. use `init(x) { ... min[x] = $2; max[x]=$3 ...}` and get rid of `maxvalue=999999;` and then your min/max calculations will work independent of any input values.